# Regex to match word only in quotes

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to prepare a regex to match a word if it is in quotes.

i.e If the text is as follows, I want to match `HelloWorld` inside quotes but not the other one not in quotes. (should match 2nd instance of `HelloWorld` but not the 1st one)

```
HelloWorld " Showing HelloWorld"
```

**Use Case:**

I need to find text `HelloWorld` inside quotes but not other `HelloWorld` instances used as variable names or class names when I search in Eclipse IDE by regex.

Comment: Just for this string instance or are you asking how to match text inside of quotes?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect what language are you using?

Comment: @HamZa My code is in Java. I don't think that's matter as all I wanted to do was search from Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect Oh yes it does matter if you want to find several instances of `HelloWorld` that's between double quotes you might use this pattern `(?:(?:"|\G(?<!^))[^"\r\n]*?)\KHelloWorld(?=[^"\r\n]*"(?:(?:[^"\r\n]*"){2})*)`, [see demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ0hD8). The problem is that Java doesn't support the `\K` escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following.

```
'HelloWorld " Showing HelloWorld"'.match(/"(.*?)"+/g);  //["" Showing HelloWorld""]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick-and-dirty possibility you could scan the string with this:

```
/"[^"]*?"/
```

This will match the first pair of quotes (and the contained text) in the string (note the use of `*?` for a "minimal" match). Do that globally in a loop to extract text inside quotes. Every time you match a new quoted piece, check it to see if it contains what you're looking for (possibly with another regex).

This will fail if there is an escaped quote in the string, although this could of course be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

if all patterns will be like

" Showing HelloWorld"

you can match using this

```
/".+\s(\w+)"/g
```

if your language supports [:alpha:]

you can match only letters

```
/".+\s([[:alpha:]]+)"/g
```

matching against \w+ can get both letters and numbers